# How to use next() function (in python 3.7.2 )while iterating a list that contains duplicates?

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I have a string, say p = '25**VHVH**74**V**6**HV**8**VH**'. Here VHVH, V, HV, VH are called chains. 
chain1= VHVH chain2=V chain3=HV chain4=VH.

I wanted to randomnly select any one chain and complement them (means changing H to V or V to H) in the string.

For example if I pick up chain1, then my string would be p = '25**HVHV**74V6HV8VH' if i pick up chain4 then my string would be p ='25VHVH74V6HV8**HV**'

Summary:

Input: '25**VHVH**74**V**6**HV**8**VH**'

output: '25**HVHV**74V6HV8VH' or '25VHVH74**H**6HV8VH' or '25VHVH74V6**VH**8VH' or '25VHVH74V6HV8**HV**'
'

Presently I am able to get the index of starting-of-each-chain . Then using list.index() I should replace one of them, but I think its not efficient way to achieve what I want. I am stuck at this infact...

```
    pe = list(enumerate(polish_exp))
    chain_pos = {}
    for i in pe:
        if i[1] in ['H','h','V','v']:
            chain_pos.update({i[0]:[i[1]]})
            count = 0
            for j in pe[pe.index(i)+1:]:
                if j[1] in ['H','h','V','v']:
                    chain_pos[i[0]].append(j[1])
                    count += 1
                else:
                    break
    print(chain_pos)
```

Output I am getting currently for the above code

{2: ['V'], 4: ['H'], 8: ['V', 'H'], 9: ['H'], 11: ['V'], 13: ['V', 'H'], 14: ['H']}

Input: '25VHVH74V6HV8VH'

Expected output: '25HVHV74V6HV8VH' or '25VHVH74H6HV8VH' or '25VHVH74V6VH8VH' or '25VHVH74V6HV8HV'

Comment: I don't think your question matches your title, or at least it's pretty hard to find the "next()" function usage anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution on my own. And here it is!!!!

```
def complement_chain(string):
    p = dict(enumerate(string))
    chain_pos = {}
    for i in p.keys():
        if p[i] in ['H','h','V','v']:
            if p[i-1] not in ['H','h','V','v']:
                chain_pos.update({i:[p[i]]})
                for j in list(p.keys())[i+1:]:
                    if p[j] in ['H','h','V','v']:
                        chain_pos[i].append(p[j])
                    else:
                        chain_pos.update({i:''.join(chain_pos[i])})
                        break
    chosen_chain_key = random.choice(list(chain_pos.keys()))
    transtable = str.maketrans('hHvV','vVhH')
    chain_pos.update({chosen_chain_key:chain_pos[chosen_chain_key].translate(transtable)})
    l = chosen_chain_key + len(chain_pos[chosen_chain_key])
    new_string = string[:chosen_chain_key] + chain_pos[chosen_chain_key] + string[l:]
    return new_string
```

Test inp: 2HV1H37HVHV6V8VHV9

Output1: 2HV1**V**37HVHV6V8VHV9

Output2: 2HV1H37HVHV6V8**HVH**9

Output3: 2HV1H37HVHV6**H**8VHV9